# How do I commit changes to a submodule but not its parent?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-submodules

I have made a repository `A original`.

Then I made repository `B original`.

I add `A original` to `B original` as `A submodule`.

I make changes to the `A submodule` in `B original`, but I do not want to push the changes from `A submodule` to `A original`.

Is it possible to push changes to the `A submodule` without having to push them to the `A original`? And then would it be possible to merge updates from `A original`, into `A submodule`?

Is submodules a bad idea for this, and what is the more appropriate way??

Answer (score 1):

A submodule *is* a Git repository.

A Git repository is little more<sup>1</sup> than a collection of commits.  This means that if you want something to stick around, you must put it into a commit.<sup>2</sup>

The *superproject*—the Git repository that's using a second Git repository, thus turning the second Git repository into the submodule in question—is its own separate Git repository.  In this case, `A original` is your superproject.  It has commits and for something to stick around, you must put it into a commit.  But when `A original` refers to some submodule, all it does here is store a Git *hash ID.*  This hash ID is the "true name" of *some particular commit in the submodule Git repository*.<sup>3</sup>

> Is it possible to push changes to the [submodule Git repository] without having to push them to the [superproject]?

This question is a bit malformed, because we don't actually push *changes*.  What `git push` pushes are *commits*.  Commits are not *changes:* they are *snapshots*.  Still, the concept is sound: you make some change, then you commit it, i.e., make a new snapshot by taking the changed sources and turning them into a snapshot.

If you make new commits in some repository—whatever "kind" of repository that may be: superproject, submodule, or standalone—and you want those commits to be available to other people, you not only *can* push them, you often *must* push them.  The only other way to make them available to other people is to give other people fetch/pull access to your own computer.  That tends to be a big job, which is why we mostly fob it off on hosting providers like GitHub or Bitbucket.

The tricky bit with a submodule is that if you *do* make changes to the submodule Git repository, you should then:

1. make one or more new commits;
2. deliver those commits somewhere that other people can see them (e.g., `git push` them to your hosting provider);
3. go back into your superproject repository and use the Git tools there to make a new snapshot: one which says *use the new submodule commit*.

You can include other changes in this superproject snapshot as well, but the key change is that this new commit *in the superproject* says to use the new commit *in the submodule*.

> And then would it be possible to merge updates from [the superproject], into [the submodule]?

No: the superproject *has no updates* to the submodule.  The superproject is a separate Git repository.  All it does is *refer to* some particular commits *in* the submodule.  Since the superproject merely says "go get commit `H` from submodule `X`" (for some commit hash ID `H`), there is literally *nothing to merge*.

The submodule is a collection of commits.  As long as it includes a commit with hash ID `H`, that's all the superproject needs; all the superproject can *say* is "get me hash `H`", or "get me hash `I`", or "get me hash `J`", or whatever.

Each repository *is* a Git repository:

- The submodule is a Git repository: a collection of commits (plus whatever minor other stuff it has).  It only "knows" that it's a submodule because the superproject itself cloned it and because the superproject Git keeps entering the submodule and commanding it: *check out commit _____* (fill in the blank with some raw hash ID).
- The superproject is a Git repository: a collection of commits (plus whatever other minor stuff it has).  It only "knows" that it's a superproject because it has a commit that says *clone the submodule if necessary, then check out commit _____* (fill in the blank with some raw hash ID).  The cloning instructions are in a file named `.gitmodules`; these may also get copied to your `.git/config`.  The rest—the hash ID, and the path where the clone goes—are in each commit in the superproject.

That's really all there is to submodules.  Well, OK, there's a whole bunch of interaction, mostly coded up in `git submodule`, that results *from* the above, but that's the essence of a superproject/submodule pair.  Note that a submodule Git repository can itself be a superproject, i.e., it can have its own submodules.  All it has to do is list some Git repository to clone, and some commit hash ID to check out.

---

<sup>1</sup>How much more, depends on the type of repository: a `--bare` repository is the collection of commits plus the names database (branch names, tag names, and the like); a non-bare repository also provides a *working tree*.  The working tree isn't *in* the repository, but it's where you see your files, so that can be pretty important.  Just keep in mind that while Git *provided a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) to work in*, that folder (directory) is not actually *in* the repository, it's just *next to it*.

<sup>2</sup>Things you put in your working tree will generally stick around too—with a lot of caveats—but since they're *next to*, not *in*, the repository, no *other* Git clone will be able to see them.

<sup>3</sup>Branch names are a sort of changeable alias for a commit: they'll let you *find* a commit, but someone can change the branch name later, so that you find a *different* commit.  The superproject Git insists on finding the *right* commit, so it doesn't hold a branch name, which might change: it holds a hash ID, which cannot change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But not sure if I understand, or have asked the wrong question. I will have to come back to this

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, it's not possible to commit changes made within a submodule only to the parent repository without committing them in the submodule itself. The parent repository doesn't track the content of the submodule, only the reference to a specific commit within the submodule.

If you want to make changes to the submodule's code without affecting the submodule's repository, you might consider copying the code into the parent repository or using a different method to manage dependencies.